# Dropdown Click PHP Data From mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="btn-group m-b-5">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-info">
        Ana Kategori
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php                                       
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDataTableTwo)){
                echo '<li><a onclick="myFunction()">'.$row['Ana_Kategori'].'</a></li>'; 
                echo ' <li class="divider"></li>';                                              
            }                                               
         ?>                                      
    </ul>
</div>
```

so in order to call `myFunction()` with the clicked dropdown items name, achieved by `$row['Ana_Kategori']`, how may I proceed?

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not what you actually want, but try it and let me know what you get.

change

```
 echo '<li><a onclick="myFunction()">'.$row['Ana_Kategori'].'</a></li>';
```

to

```
 echo '<li><a class="dropdown-link">'.$row['Ana_Kategori'].'</a></li>';
```

and then add this JS function

```
$(document).on('click','.dropdown-link',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var name = $this.text();
  console.log("I clicked " + name);  
});
```

Comment: @shivzuh I'm assuming you're using Bootstrap. http://jsbin.com/kutocaqixo/edit?html,js,console,output